# Combine columns from multiple TXT files to a table using sed and awk

Tags: r, bash, sed, awk

I have the files `FileA.txt`, `FileB.txt`, `FileC.txt`, etc., with the following column headers:

```
ID        Value1        Value2        Value3
```

I want to combine select columns from these files on the ID column, retaining the file names as new column header, so I get the following table

```
ID Value1fromFileA Value1fromFileB Value1fromFileC
```

I can successfully, though not optimally, do this in `R` using the `ldply()` and `cast()` functions. However, I'd like to be able to do this with some shell scripting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to obtain a list of three data frames, one per `Value`?

Comment: Considering unix' magically coined set of line-oriented text-processing tools, I find it hard to have a solution simpler than `for`-looping through a list of file descriptors to write down the columns. If you were to `cut`/`paste` the columns, that would unecessarily read your files many times -- yet I myself can't think of anything *neatier*.

Comment: @KPJ For some reason got to thinking about this again. Not sure why I originally though a hash was best, but below edit should work. Change the last echo/awk statement to whatever columns you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done faster/better, but below is simple if long and should work. Only command worth mentioning is `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort |  uniq -c | grep "^[ \t]*3" | awk '{print $2}'`, which globs files together, takes first column, produces counts for number of times each value appears, and stores those that appear 3 times.

```
#!/bin/bash

trim() {
  t="${1##*( )}"
  t="${t%%*( )}"
  echo "$t"
}

ids=$(cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort |  uniq -c | grep "^[ \t]*3" | awk '{print $2}')

for i in $ids; do
  line1=''
  line2=''
  line3=''
  for file in file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt; do
    while read line; do
      index=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
      #printf "$index\n"
      if [[ $(trim $i) == $(trim $index) ]]; then
        if [[ $line1 == '' ]]; then
          line1="$line"
        elif [[ $line2 == '' ]]; then
          line2="$line"
        else
          line3="$line"
        fi
      fi
    done < "$file"
  done

  echo "$line1 $line2 $line3" | awk '{print $1 " " $5 " " $9}'
done
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file1.txt
12 F2Value1 F3Value2 F4
35 F2Value1 F3Value2 F42
2 F2Value1 F3Value2 F43
523 F2Value1 F3Value2 F44
123 F2Value1 F3Value2 F45
$ cat file2.txt
1 F2Value1 F3Value2
12 F2Value1 F3Value2
123 F2Value1 F3Value2
523 F2Value1 F3Value2
99 F2Value1 F3Value2
$ cat file3.txt
72 F2Value1 F3Value2
12 F2Value1 F3Value2
100 F2Value1 F3Value2
111 F2Value1 F3Value2
123 F2Value1 F3Value2

$ ./script.sh
12 F2Value1 F3Value2 F4 F2Value1 F3Value2 F2Value1 F3Value2 
123 F2Value1 F3Value2 F45 F2Value1 F3Value2 F2Value1 F3Value2
```

Above used echo "$line1 $line2 $line3" | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $6 " " $7 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11}'

Comment: I can only get this to line up the row IDs in three columns, essentially like this:          `ID1 ID1 ID1  ID2 ID2 ID2  ID3 ID3 ID3`

Comment: @KPJ Could you clarify what you mean. Unless something is off, it should assume the first column in each file1.txt file2.txt and file3.txt is the ID.

Comment: The ID column is repeated three times, whereas what I want is the ID column (which is identical in each file) followed by a column with values from each of the files.

Comment: @KPJ See example output. You can print whichever columns you want, just edit the line `awk '{print $1 " " $6 " " $9}'` to be whichever columns (consider the columns to input there is essentially referring to a large file where we have columns_from_fil1 followed by collumns_from_file2, followed by collumns_from_file3)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ getline val2<"file2"  # read file "file2" to var "val2" , each time, read one line.
       split(val2,a2,FS);    # split var2 into array a2
    getline val3<"file3"     # read file "file3" to var "val3" , each time, read one line.
    split(val3,b3,FS)        # split var3 into array a3
    print $1,$2,a2[2],b3[2]
}' file1
```

Comment: Not sure I get this, what does val2, val3, a2, and b3 represent?

Comment: check if you understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
awk '
{
    q[$1]++
    a[$1,ARGIND]=$2
}

END {
    for (i in q) {
        if (q[i]==3) {
            print i, a[i,1],a[i,2],a[i,3]
        }
    }
} ' FileA.txt FileB.txt FileC.txt
```

Given files: `FileA.txt`

```
3 A31 A32 A33
5 A51 A52 A53
9 A91 A92 A93
```

`FileB.txt`

```
2 B21 B22 B23
9 B91 B92 B93
4 B41 B42 B43
5 B51 B52 B53
```

and `FileC.txt`

```
7 C71 C72 C73
9 C91 C92 C93
5 C51 C52 C53
```

The output is:

```
5 A51 B51 C51
9 A91 B91 C91
```

Comment: +1 Amazing how easy some things are in awk if you know how to use it.

Comment: @BroSlow Agree, awk is fun :)